# Search Subfolders with Lucene

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I have built windows folder search for a sample folder like this:

- Canada

  - Province1

    - City1
    - City2
  - Province2

    - City3
    - City4

I have done the following C# code to add the document into Lucene:

```
var textExtractionResult = new TextExtractor().Extract(file.FullName, CreateCustomResult);

            Document document = new Document();
            document.Add(new TextField("TCfilename", file.FullName, Store.YES));
            document.Add(new TextField("TCcontent", textExtractionResult.Text, Store.NO));

            //Adding Metadata
            foreach (var meta in textExtractionResult.Metadata)
            {
                document.Add(new TextField(meta.Key, meta.Value.ToString(), Store.YES));
            }

            writer.AddDocument(document);
```

How can I limit my search within a subfolder such as "Province1"?

The results should only contains the files from "Province1", "City1" and "City2".

How do I archive this with Lucene Query?

*Note: FullName should give the full path of the file.*

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you wan't your searches to work in general...

The most simple approach would be to index the path as a StringField instead and use wildcards:

```
new WildcardQuery(new Term("TCfilename", "C\\:\\\\Canada\\\\Province1\\\\*"))
//What else can we do? 
new WildcardQuery(new Term("TCfilename", "C\\:\\\\*\\\\Province1\\\\*"))
new WildcardQuery(new Term("TCfilename", "*\\\\Canada\\\\Province1\\\\*"))
```

Alternatively keeping the TextField, you can use Proximity searching:

```
parser.Parse(@"TCfilename: ""C Canada Province1""~0")
//What else can we do?
parser.Parse(@"TCfilename: ""Canada Province1""~0")
```

Each of them has their advantages and disadvantages.

The first one is very strict towards the path, but it allows us to base searches in the root, which the second does not (out of the box at least, we would have to add a special marker which the standard analyzer would leave in there, or create our own analyzer) - on the downside the first one is hard to get working with the QueryParser.

The second one allows more interesting searches such as a relationship between two folders at certain distances. The later also allows us to quickly find any files in any folders named "Provice1" without the penalty of a leading wildcard.

However, many of the capabilities unlocked with the second approach can be hard to understand anyways, so personally I would go with number 1 in most cases (and add explicit lower casing).